Dependencies are missing in my Express app deployed to Vercel
Ok, so I created a simple API for recovery of files stored on Firebase Storage and deployed it to Vercel for commodity, but once the deployment is done the next error is shown for firebase/storage in the logs:
Cannot find module '../deps/dicer/lib/Dicer'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/@fastify/busboy/lib/main.js
- /var/task/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js
- /var/task/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js
- /var/task/node_modules/undici/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.node.cjs.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase/storage/dist/index.cjs.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 517.22 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1

Is something wrong with using Firebase storage on a serverless Vercel deployment using ExpressJS? It's the first time I deployed a serverless Express app to Vercel that uses Firebase services, so I have no experience with this kinda weird error. Has anyone got these type errors?
This is an endpoint of my code and the imports
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const firebaseApp = require('./config/firebase');
const { getDownloadURL, getStorage, listAll, ref } = require('firebase/storage');
require('dotenv').config();

const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

app.use(cors());

app.get("/img", async (req, res) => {
  const storageRef = ref(storage, "img");

  const images = await listAll(storageRef);

  const imgs = await Promise.all(
    images.items.map((item) => getDownloadURL(item))
  );

  return res.status(200).json({
    ok: true,
    message: "Images fetched successfully",
    data: imgs,
  });
});

And my vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
}



Here back to post the answer.
I didn't know that @now/node is deprecated in favor of @vercel/node runtime as specified here, so the issue was solved by changing to "use": "@vercel/node".
I hope someone with a similar issue could find this helpful.
